# Find match over Array of RegEx in MongoDB Collection

Tags: regex, performance, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Say I have a collection with these fields:

```
{
    "category" : "ONE",
    "data": [
        {
            "regex": "/^[0-9]{2}$/",
            "type" : "TYPE1"
        },
        {
            "regex": "/^[a-z]{3}$/",
            "type" : "TYPE2"
        }
        // etc
    ]
}
```

So my input is "abc" so I'd like to obtain the corresponding type (or best match, although initially I'm assuming RegExes are exclusive). Is there any possible way to achieve this with decent performance? (that would be excluding iterating over each item of the RegEx array)

Please note the schema could be re-arranged if possible, as this project is still in the design phase. So alternatives would be welcomed.

Each category can have around 100 - 150 RegExes. I plan to have around 300 categories.
But I do know that types are mutually exclusive.

Real world example for one category:

```
type1=^34[0-9]{4}$, 
type2=^54[0-9]{4}$, 
type3=^39[0-9]{4}$, 
type4=^1[5-9]{2}$, 
type5=^2[4-9]{2,3}$
```

Comment: How many patterns or types you think you will have: 10, 100, 1000, more?

Comment: On average I'd say around 100 - 150 for each category.

Comment: but you only need to test one category per input string?

Comment: Do you know the max length of strings?

Comment: Yes, the usual test case is testing per category (although doing wide searches among categories would be handy to have). The max length of strings is about 20 chars.

Comment: I have an idea to reduce the number of testes using the most discriminant criterae (like the string length, the first character, the character classes used in the string...). Something like a hash function (cf: the art of computer programming vol.3 by Donald Knuth).

Comment: If was hoping for some magic on mongodb that would make that for me by using some indexing. It seems this might not be the case.

Comment: How many distinct values of **regex** field in the entire collection?

Comment: Each category have around 100 - 150 regex. I plan to have around 300 categories.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have a feature for searching for regex by matching string. The only way to know if a regex will match a string is to see if it matches, so you'll have to check each regexp against your input string.

Comment: So far you have shown _X_ amount of letters and numbers. The only remaining text items are punctuation. When you show a richer sampling of regex, I would say that you cannot define unique regex. I'd say there has to be overlap somewhere, yielding probably several types. So your assumption of **exclusivity** is basically invalid. Once you realize that you will realize that you will have to scan with each regex seperately, can't be avoided. The problem then becomes to assign value (weight) each type relative to other types in the weighted sequence of searches.

Comment: By saving RegExps in MongoDB as Strings, you WILL have to test **each of them** against your search string and mongoDB has some magic to help you with this (integrated ECMAscript in the core)

Comment: More info about this problem, including the usecase would help in getting a tailored answer...

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far. To @sin, the example shown was for illustration purposes, as I haven't implemented any functionality yet. But I do know that types are mutually exclusive. Unfortunately, each category may use a different way to represent it (it's factory dependent). Real world example for one category: type1=^34[0-9]{4}$, type2=^54[0-9]{4}$, type3=^39[0-9]{4}$, type4=^1[5-9]{2}$, type5=^2[4-9]{2,3}$ and so on. Other category may use letters only, other may use letters and digits, etc.

Comment: I also came to the same conclusion that the possible best way to implement this would be assigning some dynamic weight every time a regex is matched, thus leaving the most frequent expressions at the start of the array. I was just hoping that mongodb would do some of this automagically.

Comment: @CSᵠ Can you expand on what magic would MongoDB provide me? So far my approach was finding() the right category, and forEach on the data array to find the matching expression, as wdberkeley suggested. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dan: could you add more real world examples to your original question (in particular how looks patterns from other categories). Note that the five patterns you show are bounded by these ranges `340000-349999, 540000-549999, 390000-399999, 155-199, 244-2999` (and keep in mind that you can define ranges with other characters than digits). So you can drasticly reduce the number of patterns to test if you include the range (min and max) for each type. In this case you only need a basic query that tests the range first and only after you need to test the pattern to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing the RegEx (*Divide et Impera*) would greatly help in limiting the number of Documents needed to be processed.

Some ideas in this direction:

- **RegEx accepting length** (fixed, min, max)
- **[POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) style character classes** (`[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:alnum:]`, etc.)
- *Tree like* Document structure (umm)

Implementing each of these would add to the complexity (code and/or manual input) for Insertion and also some overhead for describing the `searchterm` before the query.

Having mutually exclusive types in a category simplifies things, but what about between categories?

> 300 categories @ 100-150 RegExps/category => **30k to 45k** RegExps

... some would surely be *exact* duplicates if not most of them.

In this approach I'll try to minimise the total number of Documents to be stored/queried in a *reversed* style vs. your initial proposed 'schema'.
<sub>*Note: included only string lengths in this demo for narrowing, this may come naturally for manual input as it could reinforce a visual check over the RegEx*</sub>

Consider rewiting the `regexes` Collection with Documents as follows:

```
{
   "max_length": NumberLong(2),
   "min_length": NumberLong(2),
   "regex": "^[0-9][2]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE1",
     "NINE/TYPE6"
  ]
},
{
   "max_length": NumberLong(4),
   "min_length": NumberLong(3),
   "regex": "^2[4-9][2,3]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE5",
     "TWO/TYPE2",
     "SIX/TYPE8"
  ]
},
{
   "max_length": NumberLong(6),
   "min_length": NumberLong(6),
   "regex": "^39[0-9][4]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE3",
     "SIX/TYPE2"
  ]
},
{
   "max_length": NumberLong(3),
   "min_length": NumberLong(3),
   "regex": "^[a-z][3]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE2"
  ]
}
```

.. each unique RegEx as it's own document, having Categories it belongs to (extensible to multiple types per category)

Demo Aggregation code:

```
function () {

   match=null;
   query='abc';

   db.regexes.aggregate(
    {$match: {
        max_length: {$gte: query.length},
        min_length: {$lte: query.length},
        types: /^ONE\//
        }
    },
    {$project: {
        regex: 1, 
        types: 1, 
        _id:0
        }
    }
   ).result.some(function(re){ 
       if (query.match(new RegExp(re.regex))) return match=re.types;
   });
   return match;
}
```

Return for `'abc'` query:

```
[
   "ONE/TYPE2"
]
```

this will run against only these two Documents:

```
{
   "regex": "^2[4-9][2,3]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE5",
     "TWO/TYPE2",
     "SIX/TYPE8"
  ]
},
 {
   "regex": "^[a-z][3]$",
   "types": [
     "ONE/TYPE2"
  ]
}
```

narrowed by the length `3` and having the category `ONE`.

Could be narrowed even further by implementing `POSIX` descriptors (easy to test against the `searchterm` but have to input 2 RegExps in the DB)

Answer (score 0):

Breadth first search. 
If your input starts with a letter you can throw away type 1, if it also contains a number you can throw away exclusive(numbers only or letters only) categories, and if it also contains a symbol then keep only a handful of types containing all three. Then follow above advice for remaining categories. In a sense, set up cases for input types and use cases for a select number of 'regex types' to search down to the right one.

Or you can create a regex model based on the input and compare it to the list of regex models existing as a string to get the type. That way you just have to spend resources analyzing the input to build the regex for it.